# How I use FontAwesome in input :before?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to use FontAwesome in `:before`(`\F002` Hand glass mark). But it doesn't work. (:focus works)

What do I missing?

```css
.font-awesome {
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  outline: none;
}

.font-awesome:focus {
  border-color: lightblue;
}

.font-awesome:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f002";
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="text" class="font-awesome" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cant apply pseudo class `:before` `:after` on `input` tag. Its invalid.

> *[Pseudo classes are only for container elements. You can not use them in elements like `<input>`, `<img>` etc.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)*

Try to use `span` for icon and wrap this into a `label`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
label input {
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  outline: none;
}

.font-awesome:focus {
  border-color: lightblue;
}

.font-awesome:before {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f002";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<label><input type="text" class="" /><span class="font-awesome"></span></label>
```

Comment: How do I get outline styled icons with this method?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code by Bhuwan's advice.
(I put the icon on left inside.)

CSS:

```
.keyword {
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  outline: none;
}

.keyword:focus {
  border-color: MediumTurquoise;
}

.search_icon:before {
  font: normal normal normal 15px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f002";
  color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<label>
  <span class="search_icon" />
  <input type="text" class="keyword" />
</label>
```

Comment: Why should not I use <empty /> style like input tag?Common sense?